# TypeError: $ is undefined & ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, zurb-foundation

i am trying to add foundation.js and foundation-topbar.js version 4 to page.tpl.php via theme.info in drupal 7. i can see that jquery and foundation js files added correctly  -jquery above foundation js files - but i get this errors:

```
TypeError: $ is undefined
(Foundation.zj, this, this.document)); // foundation-topbar.js line 206 

 ReferenceError: Foundation is not defined 
 (Foundation.zj, this, this.document)); // foundation-topbar.js line 206
```

[there is foundation-topbar.js](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js#L208)

Comment: Could be a conflict. Might be worth looking here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ or using `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: See [Manging JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722) for Drupal-specific information (though it's the same thing)

Answer (score 4):

You will need to add links to the script in this order:

1. Zepto or jQuery (but not both, Zepto replaces jQuery in Foundation 4)
2. foundation.js
3. foundation-topbar.js

`$` is a shorthand for jQuery calls and functions. So `$('')` is the same as `jQuery('')` Zepto uses `$` and is jQuery compatible so it is possible that you have both loading with a conflict, but without seeing the source it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Foundation' that it's looking for is the class object. you'll need to include foundation.js that's in the same directory as the js libs you're using.